# Drools : Rule firing multiple times

Tags: drools, rule-engine

I'm new to Drools and have hit a problem.

I've simplified the rule to exhibit the problem:

```
    rule "test"

    when
        $ev     : TestEvent()

        $evList : ArrayList( size >= 3 ) from collect
                  (
                     TestEvent(linkId == $ev.getLinkId())
                  ) 
    then
       System.out.println("Rule fired!")

    end
```

Basically, I want to count Events occurring on a particular Link (a Link is a section of road).  When 3 events occur on the same Link I want the rule to fire.

The rule above is almost working, but when it fires, it fires 3 times, once for each event.  I only want it to fire once.

What am I missing?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first pattern picks any TestEvent irrespective of its linkId. If there are n TestEvent facts with a certain linkId, the acivation proceeds n times.

To restrict this rule to fire once you could select a single TestEvent out of any such group of n. Any attribute with a unique ordered value may be used, and if you have events also the event timestamp is available.

```
rule "test"
when
    $ev: TestEvent( $lid: linkId )
    not TestEvent( linkId == $lid, this before $ev )
    $evList : ArrayList( size >= 3 ) from collect
              (
                 TestEvent(linkId == $lid)
              ) 
then
   System.out.println("Rule fired!")
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply - a useful approach.  I actually re-thought what I was doing and changed the way I've structured my design.  I've posted the solution I went with below, but marked this as the answer because it is probably useful to others.

Answer (score 1):

I got this working by changing my approach to the problem.  I've created Link objects now and then tie the events back to the Link.

The rule ends up

```
rule "test"

    when
        $link   : Link()
        $events : ArrayList( size >= 3 ) from collect (TestEvent(link == $link)) 
    then 
        System.out.println("Rule fired!")

end
```

This only fires once per link which is what I need.

Comment: This is one of the more elaborate alternatives. The other one uses rules to create, update and (optionally) delete a "Collect" fact for each set of TestEvent facts with a certain linkId. This way, you don't have to mess with the TestEvent itself, you don't need the collect and other possibilities can be implemented easily.